# Should I use rand() or rand_r()?

Tags: c++, cppcheck, cpplint

I'm trying to get a random number in C++ and I'm using `rand()`. This is what [cpplint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpplint) says:

> Consider using `rand_r(...)` instead of `rand(...)` for improved thread safety.

I'm switching to `rand_r` and this is what [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck/) says:

> Obsolete function 'rand_r' called. It is recommended to use the function 'rand' instead.

Who is right?

Comment: If possible, use the "new" `<random>` facilities. `rand` is pretty bad. [Interesting](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both, sort of.

The `rand()` function is defined by the C standard, and has been since the first such standard in 1989/1990; it's included by reference in the C++ standard. Since `rand()` depends on state, it is not thread-safe.

The `rand_r()` function was designed as a thread-safe alternative to `rand()`. It is *not* defined by the ISO C or C++ standard. It was defined by POSIX.1-2001, but marked as obsolete by POSIX.1-2008 (meaning that it's still defined by the POSIX standard, but it may be removed in a future version).

Implementations of `rand()`, and therefore of `rand_r()`, can be low quality. There are much better pseudo-random number generators. For C++, the `<random>` library was added in C++11, and provides a number of different options.

If you want maximum portability *and* you don't care too much about the quality or predictability of the generated numbers *and* thread-safety is not a concern, you can use `srand()` and `rand()`. Otherwise, if you have a C++11 implementation available, use the features defined in the `<random>` header. Otherwise, consult your system's documentation for other pseudo-random number generators.

References: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rand.html), [`<random>` on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: It may be worthy to note that C++11's random also exists in Boost for those who can't use C++11 but can use Boost.

Answer (score 1):

Use stuff from `<random>` of C++11.

Watch [rand() considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) by S.T.L.